# Comparison between two definitions of real projective spaces.

Tags: differential-topology, projective-space

The most common definitions of real projective spaces are:

- $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P} ^n = (\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - 0)/ \sim$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-0$ satisfies $x \sim y$ iff $x = \lambda y$
  for such a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*$;
- $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P} ^n = S^n / \sim_1$, where $\sim_1$ is the classical antipodal equivalence.

Where can I find a complete and rigorous proof that the two definitions are equivalent, in the sense that the two structures are diffeomorphic as differentiable manifolds?
I clearly see the point by an intuitive point of view, but I need a rigorous proof.

Edit:
Yes, the answers recevied are ok.
Furthermore, I have found a complete and detailed proof on the book "Introduction to Global Analysis", by Donald W. Kahn [pag. 40, Proposition 2.1]

Comment: In the first definition, if you take only $\lambda >0$, the resulting space is $S^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider
$$i: S^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^{n+1}$$
the inclusion and
$$p: \Bbb R^{n+1}\longrightarrow\Bbb{RP}^n$$
the quotient (first definition) map. The composition
$$p\circ i: S^n\longrightarrow\Bbb{RP}^n$$
is smooth (why?). What is $S^n/(p\circ i)$ (points with the same image are identified)?

Comment: Thank you Martìn, but please may I can ask you a clarification? For instance, why $p \circ i$ is smooth?
I think it could be that $p$ is smooth, and so their composition...but I am getting confuse in understanding why the projection is smooth...

Comment: @Biagio, consider near (say) $(0,\cdots,0,1)$ the function $\Bbb R^{n+1}\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ $(x_1/x_{n+1},\cdots,x_n/x_{n+1})$ and use it to construct a chart of $\Bbb{RP}^n$ (first definition). Study the differentiability of $p$ using the chart. Cheat sheet: http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~idarcy/COURSES/133/3_2rpns.pdf

Comment: thank you for the comment.
Now the point is the following: let $p$ be a chart $\phi^{-1}$ as stated in the link, actually a smooth and injective map
$p: \Bbb R^{n+1}\longrightarrow\Bbb{RP}^n$. Consequently, because $i$ is smooth and injective too, so is their composition.
As a result we have the map
$p \circ i: S^n \longrightarrow \Bbb{RP}^n$ smooth and injective. I suppose, but I am not so sure, that the quotient $p\circ i: S^n/(p\circ i) \longrightarrow\Bbb{RP}^n$ becomes smooth, bijective and with inverse smooth...is it true? How can I prove it?

Comment: $p\circ i$ isn't injective ($p$ neither), but is surjective and *locally* injective. The quotient map is bijective and... See also http://www2.math.uu.se/~tkragh/1MA259-2013/Solution-3.5.pdf.